# Create definer Mysql :ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure but the MySQL command line gives me this error:

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> use publisher$$
Database changed
mysql> create definer='ashix'@'localhost' procedure 'GroupBookProc' (IN groupIdBook varchar(6))
    -> BEGIN
    -> select * from GroupBook where groupID = groupIdBook;
    -> END $$

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''GroupBookProc' (IN groupIdBook varchar(6))
BEGIN
select * from GroupBook where ' at line 1
```

What may I do?

Comment: Remove quotes from 'GroupBookProc'....https://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx ...Check [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/it4pum3o5c71MXUQ1RNE6q/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, @ErgestBasha
I remove quotes from 'GroupBookProc' and it works